# Setting up Tor in PuTTY

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ssh

How does one set up Tor in PuTTY? I'm using the Tor Browser Bundle on Windows 8.1.

I came across https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/Putty but the screenshot containing the proper settings has since been taken offline.

> The above image shows the settings exactly as they should be set for
>   usage with Tor. Pay particular attention to the "Do DNS lookup at
>   proxy end:" option. If this is set to Off or Auto, then DNS will leak
>   information about what services are being used.