# How to connect to onion service via PuTTY

Tags: onion-services, windows, help, ssh

I have set up an onion service on a machine (running Ubuntu Server 22.04) that provides both web and SSH access, such that this is the torrc:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/myservice/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

If I go to `myservice.onion` in Tor browser on any operating system, the website loads successfully, and when I run the following command on Linux I can login successfully:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="/usr/bin/nc -xlocalhost:9050 -X5 %h %p" username@myservice.onion
```

I can also login successfully if I define settings for `*.onion` hosts in my `~/.ssh/config` file, therefore logging in through SSH on Linux is not a problem.

However, I am unable to login on windows using the above command (since `/usr/bin/` is not a valid directory), so I tried to use PuTTY (I have release 0.76 installed) to login. I read [this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4802/setting-up-tor-in-putty), which seems to have no answers, as well as the [Tor project PuTTY guide](https://gitlab.torproject.org/legacy/trac/-/wikis/doc/TorifyHOWTO/Putty), which said to configure the proxy settings such that PuTTY is using a SOCKS5 proxy, `Proxy hostname` is `localhost`, the port is `9050`, DNS name lookup is set to `yes`, and the Telnet command field contains `connect %host %port\n`.

When I configure those exact settings, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40uJv.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWNg3.jpg), I simply get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqwxL.jpg) error. (I have the latest version of Tor Browser for Windows running while PuTTY is running, so the localhost proxy should work).

My question is, how do I connect to my onion service via PuTTY? Alternatively, is there any other way to connect to it via SSH on Windows?

Comment: The default Tor Browser SOCKS port is 9150, not 9050. You should try that instead.

Comment: @Steve Thank you, I changed the port to 9150 instead of 9050, and I was able to successfully login to the onion service. I find it strange that the Tor project documentation, as well as the Linux box running the onion service, both showed port 9050.

Comment: The tor daemon's proxy (for example what you get if you run `apt install tor`) uses port 9050. The Tor Browser's proxy uses port 9150 instead so that it doesn't conflict with the tor daemon if you have that installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steve pointed out in a comment, the solution is to keep the same settings, but set the PuTTY SOCKS5 proxy to run on port **9150**, after which the SSH login works successfully.