# Can tor be used with PUTTY to create a ssh without revealing my ip or other credentials?

Tags: ssh

Is the above question possible or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to onion service via PuTTY](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/23172/how-to-connect-to-onion-service-via-putty)